# Access Playfab data with Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, playfab

How can I access to read/write/modify/delete Playfab data with Azure functions?

Comment: But, I am using the Azure portal, so I created there the HTTP function. How can I add or refer those files? I tried without lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Below Steps will help you in accessing the azure functions with Playfab

1. Create Azure Function in VS Code
2. Deploy the azure function to portal and register your function with cloud script
3. Below is the sample example code for calling cloud script using azure functions from your playfab.

```html
//This snippet assumes that your game client is already logged into PlayFab.

using PlayFab;
using PlayFab.CloudScriptModels;

private void CallCSharpExecuteFunction()
{
    PlayFabCloudScriptAPI.ExecuteFunction(new ExecuteFunctionRequest()
    {
        Entity = new PlayFab.CloudScriptModels.EntityKey()
        {
            Id = PlayFabSettings.staticPlayer.EntityId, //Get this from when you logged in,
            Type = PlayFabSettings.staticPlayer.EntityType, //Get this from when you logged in
        },
        FunctionName = "HelloWorld", //This should be the name of your Azure Function that you created.
        FunctionParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "inputValue", "Test" } }, //This is the data that you would want to pass into your function.
        GeneratePlayStreamEvent = false //Set this to true if you would like this call to show up in PlayStream
    }, (ExecuteFunctionResult result) =>
    {
        if (result.FunctionResultTooLarge ?? false)
        {
            Debug.Log("This can happen if you exceed the limit that can be returned from an Azure Function, See PlayFab Limits Page for details.");
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log($"The {result.FunctionName} function took {result.ExecutionTimeMilliseconds} to complete");
        Debug.Log($"Result: {result.FunctionResult.ToString()}");
    }, (PlayFabError error) =>
    {
        Debug.Log($"Opps Something went wrong: {error.GenerateErrorReport()}");
    });
}
```

[PlayFab CloudScript Context, Variables and Server SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/automation/cloudscript-af/quickstart#playfab-cloudscript-context-variables-and-server-sdks-)

1. You will need to install the PlayFab SDK via Package Manager. To do this open Terminal or CMD Console in Visual Studio Code and type:  `dotnet add package PlayFabAllSDK`
2. We have created some helpers that will ship with the cSharpSDK.
3. You need to edit your .csproj file and include  `<DefineConstants>NETCOREAPP2_0</DefineConstants>`  in your default PropertyGroup or NETCOREAPP3_1 if you are using the latest.

   [image: Define Constants]
4. Execution of a script can occur through several methods (APIs, Scheduled Tasks, PlayStream Event, Segment Entering and Exit method). The context of the execution is important to implement your CloudScript. See the  [Using CloudScript context models tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/automation/cloudscript-af/cloudscript-af-context)  for details on how to use the context of the script.

For further information check [Cloud Script Using Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/automation/cloudscript-af/quickstart)  and [Playfab Cloud Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/automation/cloudscript-af/)